# SQL: Get count of rows w.r.t rows of another table

Tags: sql

I want to get the count of rows from a table belonging to a category (which are defined in another table). Kind of like the following.

```
-----------------------------------------
id  | name          |   category
    |               |
1   | Name 1        |   toddler
2   | Name 2        |   toddler
3   | Name 3        |   newborn
4   | Name 4        |   toddler
5   | Name 5        |   adult
```

And I have another table where all the categories are defined

```
-----------------------------------------
id  |  category
    |
1   |  toddler
2   |  newborn
3   |  adult
4   |  elderly
```

Now I need an SQL Query on the first table which can give me a return result something like this

```
-----------------------------------------
category   |   count
           |
toddler    |   3
newborn    |   1
adult      |   1
elderly    |   0
```

I need to count each name from Table 1 with a particular category from Table 2 and return the result.
This seems to have a fairly simple solution but I can't get my mind to work on it. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple query with `LEFT JOIN` and `COUNT`.

```
select c.category, COUNT(n.category) as count
from Table2 c
left join Table1 n on c.category = n.category
group by c.category
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60aac/1)

Comment: Thanks. But I'm getting the result of 1 for the count of rows that should be zero. Rest are good.

Comment: Like, the count for 'elderly' should be 0 but I'm getting 1.

Comment: @AliHaideri I added SQL Fiddle to show how it works.

Comment: Your previous edit was COUNT(*) which I used. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Use a **left join** on your Table2 with Table1, then use the **count** function on category and do **group by** on category.

```
select b.category, count(a.category)
from Table1 as a
left join Table2 as b
on a.id = b.id
group by b.category
```